# An if...else with two setStates causing an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this code is resulting in an infinite loop.

I'm trying to render a button and text that shows how many times the button has been clicked until it's been clicked 10 times, after which the button is supposed to disappear and the text rerender to whatever it was before + "and now it's gone".

```
class button extends React.Component 
{
constructor (props) 
{
    super(props)

    this.state = 
    {
        num: 0,
        para: null
    }
}

render() {

    var myString = <p> you clicked the button {this.state.num} times {this.state.para} </p>;

    let either;
    if (this.state.num < 10 ) {
        either = (
        <Button onClick={() => { this.handleButtonClick() }} bsStyle="danger"> button </Button> )
    } else { 
        either = null;
        this.setState({ para: "and now it's gone" });
    }

    return(
        <Grid>
            <Row>
                <Col xs={7} sm={7} md={7} lg={7}> {myString} </Col>
                <Col xs={5} sm={5} md={5} lg={5}> 
                            { either }
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Grid>
    )
}
handleButtonClick () {
    this.setState({
        num: this.state.num + 1
    })
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The specific error in question is "setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor)."

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: don't use `setState` within `render`

Answer (score 3):

setState calls for a re-render and you have a call to setState in your render method.

Comment: I've been hearing that it's not ok to use a setstate in render because it calls a re-render, thus firing setstate again, causing an infinite loop. Perhaps that's incorrect?